# Perforce switching head to new branch

Tags: perforce-integrate

The current head of a certain project I am working on is changelist 123 and has  files C, D and E.

9 submissions ago the code was completely refactored, hence, 10 submissions ago, let's call it changelist 11, the project only had files A, B and C (C being totally different from changelist 123 version of it, ofc).

Stuff happened and I had to branch from changelist 11. I now have to submit the code, and my submission will be the new head.
What I am not sure is how to integrate so that all and only files from changelist 9 are present in the head after my submission (that is, all the fiels in changelist 123 are "deleted").

I've tried looking for solutions but I clearly found the wrong info, as I was being required to manually delete all the files... The project, clearly, is not 3 files only, and with git you can do this pretty easily, so I assume there is a proper way to do this in perforce too.

Any hint is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
Maybe clearer is to say: My head is 123, I want to branch (in a tree sense) from revision 11 and create revision 124, which will now be head. As such, when I submit the project head in the depot will not contain any file/changes related to revisions 12 to 123.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but the *easiest* way is to use P4V. Right-click on the file and choose *Rollback...* and select "Rollback file to: Revision" and enter "123".  Then click on the "Submit..." button.

Comment: That was a thing I wanted to avoid.

I wanted to preserve the history as in the future we will switch back to revision 123 and proceed from there, after merging my changes.

I guess I'll go with it, thanks.

Comment: It will preserve the history. Your new revision will be #124, but you can ALWAYS get back to previous revisions (unless you choose to explicitly obliterate them, but why would you do that?).